# break lines with \includegraphics[draft] option

Tags: line-breaking, draft

When I am using \includegraphics with the draft option

```
\includegraphics[draft]{long-image-name}
```

the image name is shown instead of the image. Unfortunately it appears on one line without lines breaks, so that it extends to the beyond the border and becomes unreadable. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: That's `\texttt`, most likely, this doesn't break

Answer (score 2):

A horrible hack. But, hey! It works!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Gin@setfile}
 {\edef\@tempa{#3}\rlap{ \ttfamily\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@tempa}}
 {\breitling@draftfilename{#3}}
 {}{\ddt}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_breitling_filename_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\breitling@draftfilename}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_breitling_filename_tl { #1 }
  \rlap{~\parbox{.9\Gin@req@width}{\small\ttfamily\raggedright
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_breitling_filename_tl { ##1 \hspace{0pt} }
  }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{long-file-name-about-ducks-that-is-meant-to-be-very-very-long}
\end{document}
```

Small height or width and a very long name might make the file name overlap the text above and below the rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Wow, what a hack! Thank you! I wish a solution would be implemented in \includegraphics because this is really an extreme hack and obfuscating tex files. Nevertheless I think it is important because without it the draft option is useless.